# Graph Adjacency List Implementation

Tags: c#, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

I am trying to represent a Graph in `Adjacency List` using C#, like the code bellow.
**But I would like to know where I can find a better implementation in C#.
Like this website for Java: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/Graph.java.html**

In order to improve this implementation I have some question:

1. Is there another simple data structure to use, and that you able to make operations like `DFS`,`BFS`, `Find the Shortest-path` easier ? Or the data structure vary too much according to the problem to be solved ?

**=== EDITED ===**

I've tried to implement the data structure as bellow.

**OBS**: This approach seems simple, but I realize later that is not very suitable for a DFS, for example, since you need to keep track of the first element of the `LinkedList` all the time.In my solution Seems that is better to use a custom created Linked List, instead of
    `LinkedList<Vertex>`.

Considering the comments bellow and to maintain simplicity I made some changes. But I don't know if that changes would affect further operations, like a `BFS`.
To be able to have direct and indirect Graph I think is better to use an interface than a property.

```
 public interface IGraph
    {
        void InsertEdge(int edgeAKey, int edgeBKey);
        void IsertNewVertex(int vertexKey);
        LinkedList<Vertex> FindByKey(int vertexKey);
        bool ExistKey(int vertexKey);
    }
```

To make it as simple as possible we can use already implemented data structures like `Dictionary` and `LinkedList`. And instead of using an `object` as `Dictionary key`, to make it simple we can create in `Vertex` a `key` (or `label`) and a `value`, if you would like to add a value that already exist in another `Vertex`.

```
public class GraphDirect : IGraph
    {
        private Dictionary<int,LinkedList<Vertex>> Vertexes { get; set; }

        public GraphDirect()
        {
            Vertexes = new Dictionary<int, LinkedList<Vertex>>();
        }

        public bool ExistKey(int vertexKey)
        {
            if (this.FindByKey(vertexKey) == null)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        public void IsertNewVertex(int vertexKey)
        {
            if (!this.ExistKey(vertexKey))
            {
                Vertex vertex = new Vertex(vertexKey);
                LinkedList<Vertex> listVertexes = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
                listVertexes.AddFirst(vertex);
                this.Vertexes.Add(vertexKey, listVertexes);
            }
        }

        public void InsertEdge(int vertexAKey, int vertexBKey)
        {
            //Create the vertex A, if it doesn't exist            
            if (!this.ExistKey(vertexAKey))
            {
                this.IsertNewVertex(vertexAKey);
            } 
            //Will always insert the vertex B on this edge
            this.FindByKey(vertexAKey).AddLast(new Vertex(vertexBKey));
            //Create the vertex B, if doesn't exist
            if (!this.ExistKey(vertexBKey))
            {
                this.IsertNewVertex(vertexBKey);
            }
        }

        public LinkedList<Vertex> FindByKey(int vertexKey)
        {
            if (this.Vertexes.ContainsKey(vertexKey))
                return this.Vertexes[vertexKey];

            return null;
        }

    }
```

The Vertex class doesn't need any other pointer, just keep the `key` and a `value`, if necessary.

```
public enum State { Visited = 0, UnVisited = 1, Processed = 2 }

public class Vertex
{
    public int Key;
    public int Value;
    public State Status = State.UnVisited;

    public Vertex(int key)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = 0;
    }

    public Vertex(int key, int value)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class Start
{
     public static void Main(){
         GraphDirect gDirect = new GraphDirect();
         gDirect.InsertEdge(2, 3);
         gDirect.InsertEdge(2, 8);
         gDirect.InsertEdge(5, 6);
     }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `Vertex` as a dictionary key, you need to implement its `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides; that will probably solve your duplicate key issue. EDIT: Not sure on the rest of it though. `FindByValue` immediately throws off warning sirens seeing it iterate through the dictionary rather than looking up by some kind of ID.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thanks to let me know it, I will just make some changes and update my question.

Comment: Old question, but I personally found [this resource](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/40graphs/) super helpful for anything graph algorithm related.  It's in java, but you could easily port to C#.